# Android add layout childs

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, addchild

I'm creating my own custom LinearLayout, and extending it's class I need to add children to the layout using the addview method,

I need to have access on the tag, which is set after the constructor, so please I need to know the best practice for doing something like this

here's my code:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);


        MyTag tag = (MyTag) getTag();


        // Parent layout
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setBackgroundColor(tag.getBgColor());
    }

}
```

Comment: getTag() will always return null in constructor. (you can't set it, until construct object)

Comment: Okay guys I know the issue and need another way or method that will be called once on layout display ... I checked onLayout method by think it's called several times and caused the code to run many times ... need a more professtional way

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have access on the tag, which is set after the constructor,
>   so please I need to know the best practice for doing something like
>   this

If you set the tag **after** the constructor is called then your code will not work, the `tag` will be `null`. If you plan to use the custom `LinearLayout` only in code(not in the xml layout) then you always have the possibility of adapting your constructor to take an extra `MyTag` object:

```
// ...
public MyLayout(Context context, MyTag theTag) {
    super(context);
    MyTag tag = theTag;
//...
```

Of course this will work if you can build a valid `MyTag` object at the moment the constructor is called(when you instantiate a new object of type `MyLayout`). Anyway, if your code is so dependent on the `MyTag` object you should always have a default one in the `MyLayout` class so you can use it when the tag hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Dear, that's the implementation I'm running now, but need a more clean and organized way, I need not to fill the constructor with other business .. and btw if you have an example for inflating and xml instead will be cool

Comment: @Smartdog There is no other way. You're basically trying to use a field of a class in the constructor before it was initialized. `getTag` will return `null` in the constructor because the tag isn't yet set and it will be null until you use `setTag` or pass it directly in the constructor(like in my answer). In the xml layout, the only possible value for a tag is a `String` object, so your custom object will not work.

Comment: I know it well and that's why I'm trying to put my code in another function so that the setTag() will be called later in my code ... as I mentioned in the other comment, I tried the onLayout method but it's called regularly by android framework which will not be nice, if you have another method that is called once before inflating, it will be perfect method for me